# Rails - Search POstgres JSONB column based on key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a table abcs with denom_qty jsonb column. The value stored will be in the format

```
{"100"=>5, "1000"=>2}
```

I want to filter all the rows where the denom_qty colum has key >= a given value say 100.

I am aware that if the data is stored in the format

{ "denomination" => 100, "quantity"=> 2}. then I found multiple answers. But as the data structure cannot be changed now, how can I query all rows which has denom_qty colum's key greater than 100 ?

Comment: Are the keys standard across all the records?

Comment: No, they are dynamic.

Comment: Is this not doable in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a function based on json key values and check there is key is greater than 100.
Eg.

```
create function jsonkey( inpt jsonb)
returns jsonb
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
keyobj text[];
BEGIN
select array_agg(a.data) from(select jsonb_object_keys('{"100":5, "1000":2, "5":41}'::jsonb) as data )a into keyobj;

For i in select (keyobj)
LOOP
    if(i >=100) THEN
        return '{"100":5, "1000":2, "5":41}'::jsonb->>i;
    ELSE
        return '{}'::josnb;
    END IF;

END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Hope this help.